# In Bootstrap, how do I left align my button with the element above?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/sf4wkyx0/

My 'Add' button isn't quite left aligned with the textarea:

[image]

But both are preceded by an element with class `col-2` so I'm not sure why the alignment is slightly off.

How do I left align my 'Add' button exactly with the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **pl-0** of your button section's parent, it will be fine.

```
<div class="row col-12 mb-2 pl-0">
  <div class="col-2 spacer"></div>
  <div class="col-10 pl-0 d-inline">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto"> Add </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check this https://jsfiddle.net/7r0b8voj/

Answer (score 0):

You were nesting you `.row` classes incorrectly. Just fix the nesting issue and it should be all good.

According to [**Bootstrap's own API documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), when [**nesting columns**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) any columns `.col` should be nested within a `.row`. The two should not be combined on a single element.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="modal-body-scrolled border-primary border-bottom p-0 mt-2">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="duration" class="col-2 pl-0">Description</label>
      <div class="col-10 pl-0 d-inline">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 spacer"></div>
      <div class="col-10 pl-0 d-inline">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto"> Add </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```